# cant Get Original Index from Filtered list view

Tags: java, android, listview, baseadapter, android-filterable

I have a listview and an editText to filter data. It filters data correctly but e.g, if I filter list and open filtered item it shows me the data of item which was at index 0 of original list not that of filtered item.

My Adapter class:

```
public class Patient_Adapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable{

Activity context;
String[] name, age, number, dip_rate;

//for filtering use arraylists
LayoutInflater inflater;
private ValueFilter valueFilter;
ArrayList<ArrayList_get_set> arrayList;
private ArrayList<ArrayList_get_set> StringFilterList;

public Patient_Adapter(Activity applicationContext, ArrayList<ArrayList_get_set> arrayList) {

    this.context     = applicationContext;
    /////
    this.arrayList   = arrayList;
    StringFilterList = arrayList;
    this.inflater    = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    getFilter();

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return arrayList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return arrayList.get(i);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return 0;
}


private class Viewholder{

    TextView name_
            ,date_
            ,number_
            ,dip_rate_
            ,tv_request_number;
    Button button;

}


@Override
public View getView(final int position, View view, final ViewGroup viewGroup) {


    Viewholder viewholder;

    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();

    if (view == null){

        viewholder = new Viewholder();
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.patient_item_list,null);

        viewholder.tv_request_number = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.s_req_num);
        viewholder.name_     = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
        viewholder.button    = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_re);
        viewholder.date_     = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.date);


        view.setTag(viewholder);

    }
    else {

        viewholder = (Viewholder) view.getTag();
    }

    viewholder.tv_request_number.setText((arrayList.size()-position)+".");
    viewholder.name_.setText(arrayList.get(position).getName());
    viewholder.date_.setText(getDate(Long.parseLong(arrayList.get(position).getDate())));

    viewholder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            ((ListView)viewGroup).performItemClick(v,position,1);
        }
    });

    return view;
}


//Filter Results
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {

    if(valueFilter==null) {

        valueFilter=new ValueFilter();
    }

    return valueFilter;
}


private class ValueFilter extends Filter {

    //Invoked in a worker thread to filter the data according to the constraint.
    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
        if(constraint != null && constraint.length()>0){
            ArrayList<ArrayList_get_set> filterList = new ArrayList<>();
            for(int i=0;i<StringFilterList.size();i++){
                if((StringFilterList.get(i).getName().toUpperCase())
                        .contains(constraint.toString().toUpperCase())) {
                    ArrayList_get_set contacts = new ArrayList_get_set();
                    contacts.setName(StringFilterList.get(i).getName());
                    contacts.setDate(StringFilterList.get(i).getDate());

                    filterList.add(contacts);
                }
            }
            results.count=filterList.size();
            results.values=filterList;
        }else{
            results.count=StringFilterList.size();
            results.values=StringFilterList;
        }
        return results;
    }


    //Invoked in the UI thread to publish the filtering results in the user interface.
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                                  FilterResults results) {
        arrayList = (ArrayList<ArrayList_get_set>) results.values;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

This my main activity code

```
simListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            if(id == 1){

                //CUSTOM DIALOG///////////////////////////////
                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
                dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_re_evaluate);

                name_     = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.name);
                f_name_   = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.f_name);
                age_      = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.age);
                number_   = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.number);
                gender_   = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.gender);
                dip_rate_ = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dip_rate);
                date_     = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.date);


                name_.setText(name[position]);
                f_name_.setText(f_name[position]);
                age_.setText(age[position]);
                number_.setText(number[position]);
                dip_rate_.setText(dip_rate[position]);
                gender_.setText(gender[position]);
                date_.setText(getDate(Long.parseLong(date[position])));

                Button re_eval    = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn);
                Button btn_cross  = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.cross);

                btn_cross.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });


                re_eval.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        p_name     = name_.getText().toString();
                        p_f_name   = f_name_.getText().toString();
                        p_age      = age_.getText().toString();
                        p_number   = number_.getText().toString();
                        p_dip_rate = dip_rate_.getText().toString();
                        p_gender   = gender_.getText().toString();
                        p_date     = date_.getText().toString();

                        //go from one fragment to another
                        Fragment fragment = null;
                        //send data to next fragment
                        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                        bundle.putString("name", p_name);
                        bundle.putString("f_name", p_f_name);
                        bundle.putString("age", p_age);
                        bundle.putString("number", p_number);
                        bundle.putString("dip_rate", p_dip_rate);
                        bundle.putString("gender", p_gender);
                        bundle.putString("date", p_date);

                        fragment = new Questions();

                        if (fragment != null) {
                            FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                            fragment.setArguments(bundle);
                            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
                            ft.commit();
                        }

                        dialog.dismiss();


                    }
                });


                dialog.show();
            }
        }
    });
```

performing filtering here

```
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {

        progressDialog.dismiss();

        if (server_check) {

            if (server_response.equals("1")) {

                if (name.length > 0) {

                    patient_adapter = new Patient_Adapter(getActivity(),
                            arrayList);
                    simListView.setAdapter(patient_adapter);


                    //filtering data
                    search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                        @Override
                        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int start, int count, int after) {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int start, int before, int count) {

                            patient_adapter.getFilter().filter(charSequence);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: Where do you perform filtering?

Comment: @MichaelSpitsin updated my code

Comment: @MichaelSpitsin will you please help me actually the problem is here i get the filtered data but e.g, in a list of 20 item when i filter an item and click to see its information i get the details of item which was at index 0 of original list not getting the details of filtered item. I am not  Getting Original Index from Filtered list view

Comment: yes i want complete code @pskink